# How can visitors redirect wp-admin to the homepage?

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, buddypress, content-restriction

How can visitors redirect wp-admin to the homepage?

**My site details:**
1. I used BuddyPress;
2. Users can sign up and login via BuddyPress;
3. User role only Admin and Author;

**Needs:**
1. wp-admin only admin can access, if not an admin, and visitors and Authors then redirect to home page;
2. Users force use BuddyPress login page.

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: What have you researched so far? What have you tried?

Comment: You can use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wps-hide-login/ ( I am not the developer of this plugin or not affiliated with them ) to change/hide your default wordpress login page and then use a 301 redirect plugin. This way, only admin will know where login page really exists and the authors or visitors will not have a clue about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [codex entry for the `admin_init` hook has an example](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init) showing you how to do this.

```
/**
 * Restrict access to the administration screens.
 *
 * Only administrators will be allowed to access the admin screens,
 * all other users will be automatically redirected to
 * 'example.com/path/to/location' instead.
 *
 * We do allow access for Ajax requests though, since these may be
 * initiated from the front end of the site by non-admin users.
 */
function restrict_admin_with_redirect() {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && ( ! wp_doing_ajax() ) ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( 'example.com/path/to/location' ); // Replace this with the URL to redirect to.
        exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'restrict_admin_with_redirect', 1 );
```

A few notes on how this works:

- `current_user_can( 'manage_options' )` checks to see if the logged in user has a capability only admin accounts should have. The proceeding `!` means "not". We are checking for a capability instead of simply checking for the admin role as a best practice. You should treat the role as nothing more than a label and check for capabilities (read: permissions) to check if a user can do something. [Read more about the roles & caps here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).
- `wp_doing_ajax()` Makes sure the current request is not a WordPress Ajax request. If it is, it's possible the user is not actually on the admin so no need to redirect. The proceeding `!` means "not".
- `wp_safe_redirect( 'example.com/path/to/location' );` Redirects the user to the URL you pass it. [You can find the documentation here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_redirect/). *Note: `wp_safe_redirect()` is the recommended function not `wp_redirect()`*. Thanks @Nathan Johnson

  - `exit;` Stops execution of the script making the redirect the last action we do.
- `add_action( 'admin_init', 'restrict_admin_with_redirect', 1 );` Fire this check on the [`admin_init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init) because it's the first hook fired after authentication. Pass `1` as the last argument to make sure out function is fired before any other hooks.

Comment: You should use [`wp_safe_redirect()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_redirect/) instead of `wp_redirect()`

Comment: @Nathan Johnson good catch, updated.

Comment: Do I need to re-edit it every after updated?

Comment: Are you using a child theme? If not, this will get overwritten after an update. You should probably look into using a child theme.

Answer (score 0):

Is your own internet connection on a static IP? If so you can block wp-admin to everyone except your own IP. This is what I do. It can be achieved via various plugins but can also be done via htaccess.